# Drupal Full Calendar duplicate pagers at top

Tags: calendar, drupal-7

I started with the Drupal calendar module but there were problems with it so I switched to the Full Calendar module.

However, although the view appears correct when defining the view when I view the month view page, there are two pagers at the top - one looks like the Calendar pager and the other is the Full Calendar version. I can't get rid of the Calendar pager.

I've uninstalled Calendar and removed the module completely. I've also cleared caches,

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to remove the unwanted pager?

Comment: I discovered that i was not using the most current version of the fullcalendar jquery plugin. Now it works properly and has only one set of pagers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the most current version of the fullcalendar jquery plugin. Now it works properly and has only one set of pagers